# Let $E[X]$ be the expected value of X, what is the meaning of $E[X^n]$

Tags: probability, expected-value

I am interested to understand what's the meaning of using powers in expected value. 
Both mathematically and maybe intuitively, what does it even mean "the power of a random variable"?

Thanks!

Comment: I would like to direct your attention here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_(mathematics)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple example in the discrete case.

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ for which $$\Pr[X = -1] = 1/2, \\ \Pr[X = 1] = 1/3, \\ \Pr[X = 2] = 1/6.$$  Think of the set $\{-1, 1, 2\}$ as the set of possible outcomes of $X$, and the probability of observing one of these outcomes is described as above.

Now, if I want to ascertain the expected value of $X$, which in the frequentist viewpoint is in a sense the "long-run average" of many observations of $X$, then $$\operatorname{E}[X] = (-1)\Pr[X = -1] + (1)\Pr[X = 1] + (2)\Pr[X = 2] = -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{2}{6} = \frac{1}{6}.$$  Note that the expected value need not be one of the outcomes of $X$; in fact, $\Pr[X = 1/6] = 0$ as implied by the probability distribution I've provided.  What $1/6$ means here is that if we were to observe many realizations of $X$, and average them together, the result would tend toward $1/6$ as the number of observations increases.

So, what does something like $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$ mean?  The expression $X^2$ is another random variable that can be calculated from $X$; it means that whatever outcome $X$ is, $X^2$ is its square.  Since $X \in \{-1, 1, 2\}$, then $X^2 \in \{1, 4\}$.  We get this by taking the square of each outcome, and taking all the unique values.  The probability mass function of $X^2$ is $$\Pr[X^2 = 1] = \Pr[X = -1] + \Pr[X = 1] = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{5}{6}, \\ \Pr[X^2 = 4] = \Pr[X = 2] = \frac{1}{6}.$$  Then $$\operatorname{E}[X^2] = (1)\Pr[X^2 = 1] + (4)\Pr[X^2 = 4] = \frac{5}{6} + \frac{4}{6} = \frac{3}{2}.$$

Of course, you can similarly calculate things like $\operatorname{E}[X^3]$, $\operatorname{E}[X^4]$, and so forth.

The idea here is that $X^n$ corresponds to another random variable whose set of outcomes (its support) and probability distribution are determined by those of $X$ in a way that naturally extends from the familiar rules of algebra.  You can do this for continuous random variables too; or random variables with more complicated definitions.  Note that $\operatorname{E}[X]$ may be well-defined but $\operatorname{E}[X^n]$ may not for certain $n$; a trivial example is if $\Pr[X = 0] > 0$ and $n < 0$, in which case you'd have division by $0$.  There also exist examples where $\operatorname{E}[X^2]$ fails to exist even though $\operatorname{E}[X]$ does.